# Has any law failed a test of rational basis?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, standard-of-review

Has any federal or state law ever been struck down because it had no [rational basis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_basis_review), in a case where that was the standard for constitutionality?

Comment: One state legislature tried to pass a law defining pi as 3.2 exactly, to simplify mathematics, which was fortunately killed off before it got onto the statute books.

Comment: 3.2?  Based on simple rounding, wouldn't it be 3.1?

Comment: It wasn't based on rounding. It was based on "squaring the circle". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following article found seventeen cases between 1971 and 2014 when the Supreme Court, purportedly applying rational basis scrutiny, held that the law in question violated the equal protection clause.

[Holoszyc-Pimentel, Raphael.  "Reconciling rational-basis review: when does rational basis bite?" *New York University Law Review* **90**: 2070-2117 (2015)](https://www.nyulawreview.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/NYULawReview-90-6-Note-Holoszyc-Pimentel_1.pdf)

The article's introduction appendix to the article gives brief summaries of all seventeen.  (As well as one extra case, *Logan v. Zimmerman Brush Co.* in which the majority opinion did not mention rational-basis scrutiny, but two concurring opinions, signed by a total of six justices, did.)  The author specifically cites *Romer v. Evans* as mentioned in bdb484's answer.  Another quotable example is [*USDA v. Moreno*, 413 U.S. 528 (1973)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/413/528/), which examined a provision that denied food stamps to households where unrelated people were living together (e.g. hippie communes).  Its second-to-last sentence:

> But the classification here in issue is not only "imprecise," it is wholly without any rational basis.

Incidentally, Holoszyc-Pimentel's thesis is that in these cases, the Court was not truly applying rational-basis scrutiny, but some other slightly stronger standard, which the author calls "rational basis with bite".

The full list of cases from the article:

1. United States v. Windsor, 133 S. Ct. 2675 (2013);
2. Romer v. Evans, 517 U.S. 620
   (1996);
3. Quinn v. Millsap, 491 U.S. 95 (1989);
4. Allegheny Pittsburgh Coal Co. v. Cty.
   Comm’n, 488 U.S. 336 (1989);
5. City of Cleburne v. Cleburne Living Ctr., Inc., 473 U.S. 432
   (1985);
6. Hooper v. Bernalillo Cty. Assessor, 472 U.S. 612 (1985);
7. Williams v. Vermont, 472
   U.S. 14 (1985);
8. Metro. Life Ins. Co. v. Ward, 470 U.S. 869 (1985);
9. Plyler v. Doe, 457 U.S.
   202 (1982);
10. Zobel v. Williams, 457 U.S. 55 (1982);
11. U.S. Dep’t of Agric. v. Moreno, 413 U.S.
    528 (1973);
12. James v. Strange, 407 U.S. 128 (1972);
13. Jackson v. Indiana, 406 U.S. 715 (1972);
14. Weber v. Aetna Cas. & Sur. Co., 406 U.S. 164 (1972);
15. Eisenstadt v. Baird, 405 U.S. 438 (1972);
16. Lindsey v. Normet, 405 U.S. 56 (1972);
17. Reed v. Reed, 404 U.S. 71 (1971).
18. Logan v. Zimmerman Brush Co., 455 U.S. 422 (1982)

Answer (score 11):

Yes. The Supreme Court struck down Colorado's ban on enacting laws to extend legal protections on the basis of sexual orientation as having no rational basis. [*Romer v. Evans*, 517 U.S. 620 (1996)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/517/620).